# .htacees Redirect All Subdomains Except www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to edit my .htaccess code to work for all the below conditions.  Here is the .htaccess file that I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.old_domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new_domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Here is the functionality I'm looking for:

```
old_domain.com -> https://new_domain.com/     #This Works
old_domain.com/any_directory/ -> https://new_domain.com/any_directory/     #This Works
www.old_domain.com -> https://new_domain.com/     #This Works
any_subdomain_besides_www.old_domain.com -> https://any_subdomain_besides_www.new_domain.com/   #This does NOT work
```

How should I edit my .htaccess file so that last line works, along with all the other conditions? To be clear, if the subdomain on the old domain is `www`, then remove it on the new domain.  However if it is any other subdomain besides `www`, keep it in and only change the domain.  Currently it removes all subdomains. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, I don't post questions in here unless I do a diligent amount of research and can't find the answer.  I've already spent several hours trying to figure out the correct way to do this, and I've gotten this far, just couldn't figure out the last part. Just about everything I've learned has been self taught, so if you're going to down-vote this question, that's okay, just please explain why so I can improve when writing questions for next time. Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://new_domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.old_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1.new_domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is working on the .htaccess checker (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=0349ef65-6976-5932-a451-63f1d70027f0), however it's not working on my server for some reason.  I did several tests as well as deleted cache. Still trying to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I figured it out, I forgot to add a CNAME record for the DNS of the old_domain.com, so the above code is the answer.  If anyone is trying to do this, put the first pair of `RewriteCond` `RewriteRule` .htaccess file in the old_domain.com public_html directory and the last two lines in the .htaccess file in the subdomain.old_domain.com public_html directory.  And don't forget to create a CNAME for your subdomain in the DNS of your old_domain.com.  Thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Only old_domain.com with www subdomain will be redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://new_domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, this code does consolidate what I already have from three lines of code into two, and I do appreciate that, however the input of `subdomain.old_domain.com` should return `subdomain.new_domain.com` and this code does not return that.  I verified on my web server as well as an online htaccess tester tool. Thank you though. (The Rewrite Condition is not met for any subdomain besides `www`)